# Is there a node.js module that can generate 1/f (pink noise) fluctuations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, chaos, javascript-oscillator

I'm looking for a node.js module that would be able to generate fluctuations (of any sort) that would follow the `S(f) = 1/f` "pink / fractal noise" pattern. That means, that if we performed Fourier analysis of the time-series we'd find that there's a few high-amplitude fluctuations and many low-amplitude ones with the following distribution of signal:

[image]

If you don't know about the module, then maybe know some mathematical node.js toolkit that could help me generate this?

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing to do with the question but remind me that :https://www.editions-parole.net/produit/thermodynamique-de-levolution-un-essai-de-thermo-bio-sociologie/
must read :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **tooloud** library that can do what you want https://www.npmjs.com/package/tooloud